# Why does image width in percentage also affect the image height?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I am trying to make a website more responsive by using percentage instead of pixels. When I changed the image width to percentage I noticed it also affected the height. 
Could someone explain to me why this is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, an image always tries to retain proportions.
So if width or height is changed, the other will change with it.

This is the pure nature of images since otherwise they would look blurry when resized wrong.

Comment: Do not forget to upvote / accept the answer, on the left there are arrows for up and down, where the latter is downvote, below the down arrow there's a big check thing, click that to accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

When CSS changes an image's width it scales the image's height also, if the height is set to `auto` (the initial value).

This is to make it easier to e.g. put a fixed-size banner on your site without knowing its size, but still not ruin its proportions, because if you have e.g. text or squares in the image, it may look weird if resized only in one direction.

If you want to only scale it horizontally you must specify the height.

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer helps you out, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.